# DHCP snooping on distribution layer stops cliens on access from getting ip address

Tags: cisco, dhcp

Here is my topology:

```
sw1(gi0/1 trusted port)->sw2(gi0/1 trusted port)->core-sw(gi0/1)->DHCP_server
```

at the beginning i only configured sw1:

```
ip dhcp snooping
ip dhcp snooping vlan 18
int gi0/1
ip dhcp snooping trust
```

I have checked and everything is fine, all clients receive ip address from DHCP server and i see bindings on sw1.

But when i configure sw2:

```
ip dhcp snooping
ip dhcp snooping vlan 18
int gi0/1
ip dhcp snooping trust
```

and both sw1 and sw2 are configured, my clients on sw1 stops receiving ip address. Do i need to configure something else ?

Comment: ip helper address?

Comment: dhcp server is on trunk interface and see all subnets

Comment: is this layer 2 to core-sw?

Comment: sw1 is l2, sw2 is l2, core is l3 - its rouiting between vlans. All three connected by trunk link

Comment: so, there is a gotcha depending on the trunk port used - some are default untrused - have a look here http://packetpushers.net/ccnp-studies-configuring-dhcp-snooping/

Comment: Thanks for great article- it was "ip dhcp snooping information option allow-untrusted" that i should to put on sw2

Answer (score 0):

Configure following as a part of dhcp snooping config on switches

## no ip dhcp snooping information option